# Rotate array to left k cells python

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function named rotateLeft(source, k)
that rotates all the elements of the source array to the left by 'k' positions.

My code:

```
def shiftLeft(source, k):
lenth = len(source)
i = 0
while(i < (lenth - k)):
    source[i] = source[i+k]
    source[i+k] = source[i]
    i += 1

source=[10,20,30,40,50,60]
a = shiftLeft(source, 3)
print(source)
```

Expected output: `[ 40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]`

Comment: Arrays are not lists and your function returns None because it has no explicit return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you're trying to shift consecutive items from the `source` array, you're overwriting the first item `source[i]` with the second one `source[i+k]` without first saving the value from `source[i]`.

Solution:

```py
def shiftLeft(source, k):
    length = len(source)
    i = 0
    
    while(i < (length - k)):
        start = source[i]
        source[i] = source[i+k]
        source[i+k] = start
        i += 1

source=[10,20,30,40,50,60]
a = shiftLeft(source, 2)
print(source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Shifting seems to mean chopping off the left side and attaching it to the right. That's an operation that's much more efficiently done in blocks.

A solution that creates a new list without mutating the original:

```
def shift_left(a, k):
    return a[k:] + a[:k]
```

To modify the original in-place, simply re-assign the result back into the list:

```
def shift_left(a, k):
    a[:] = a[k:] + a[:k]
```

Notice that this will shift right correctly if you pass in a negative `k`.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `deque`

```py
from collections import deque

source = deque([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
k = 3

source.rotate(-k)  # in place rotation
print(source)
```

#### Limitation of `deque`

Random access to elements is not `O(1)`, that is avoid calling `source[i]` if use-case requires so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator method to rotate left or right, depending on the sign of the parameter.

Here is the method:

```
def rotate(lst, n):
    size = len(lst)
    n = n-(n//size * size)
    for idx in range(size):
        ptr = idx+n
        if ptr >= size:
            ptr -= size
        yield lst[ptr]
```

---

Given a list `lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, you can use it in this way:

```
list(rotate(lst, 1))
#=> ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

Or

```
list(rotate(lst, -1))
#=> ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can also use a value greater then the length of the list:

```
list(rotate(lst, 5))
#=> ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```